# scala.collection.mutable.HashMap cannot be cast to scala.collection.mutable.MultiMap

Tags: scala, spark-streaming

I am developing a spark streaming application using mapwithsate

the trackStateFunc is defined as folllow:

```
 def trackStateFunc(batchTime: Time, key: KEY_JOINS, value: Option[(Option[DXE_NOR], Option[NW_NOR], Option[CHG_NOR])],state: State[HashMap[KEY_JOINS, Set[(Option[DXE_NOR], Option[NW_NOR], Option[CHG_NOR])]] with MultiMap[KEY_JOINS, (Option[DXE_NOR], Option[NW_NOR], Option[CHG_NOR])]])
: Option[(KEY_JOINS, HashMap[KEY_JOINS, Set[(Option[DXE_NOR], Option[NW_NOR], Option[CHG_NOR])]] with MultiMap[KEY_JOINS, (Option[DXE_NOR], Option[NW_NOR], Option[CHG_NOR])])] =
{

 if(key.SUBSCRIBER_ID=="621300315445434" && key.CHARGING_ID=="3803685246")
 println("Key is :"+key.toString()+"Value is :"+value.toString()+"State is :"+state.getOption().toString())

if (state.isTimingOut()) {
  //write state to database

  println("State with key"+key.toString() +"is timing out")
  return None
}
//var c:HashMap[KEY_JOINS, Set[(Option[DXE_NOR], Option[NW_NOR], Option[CHG_NOR])]] with MultiMap[KEY_JOINS, (Option[DXE_NOR], Option[NW_NOR], Option[CHG_NOR])]
else if (state.exists) {
   var c = state.get()


  println("value is"+value.get.toString())

  println("c is"+c.toString())

  if(!c.entryExists(key, _==value.get)) {
    c.addBinding(key, value.get)

    state.update(c)
  }

    //println("State is :"+state.get().toString())



  Some(key, c)
}
else {


  val a = new HashMap[KEY_JOINS, Set[(Option[DXE_NOR], Option[NW_NOR], Option[CHG_NOR])]] with MultiMap[KEY_JOINS, (Option[DXE_NOR], Option[NW_NOR], Option[CHG_NOR])]
  /*
  a.addBinding(key, value.getOrElse((Some(new DXE_NOR("temp DXE", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")),
    Some(NW_NOR("temp NW", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")),
    Some(CHG_NOR("temp CHG", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "", "")))))

    */

  a.addBinding(key, value.get)
  state.update(a)
  Some(key, a)

}
}
```

However, I get exception as follow, when casting the below values...

```
value is(None,Some(NW_NOR.SUBSCRIBER_ID=621300245125288, NW_NOR.CHARGING_ID=2635156471, NW_NOR.Node_ID=, NW_NOR.Start_Time=2016-05-01 14:06:31 +01:00 ,NW_NOR.CDR_SOURCE=, NW_NOR.FILE_POPULATION_TIME=, NW_NOR.CDR_REASON=recordClosure, NW_NOR.PARTIAL_SEQ_NUM=, NW_NOR.PARTIAL_IND=, NW_NOR.TERMINATION_CAUSE=CauseForRecClosing_sGSNChange, NW_NOR.SOURCE_SEQ_NUM=1, NW_NOR.IMSI=621300245125288, NW_NOR.MSISDN=92348E+14, NW_NOR.IMEI=8.6047E+15, NW_NOR.UE_IP_ADDRESS=10.145.221.89, NW_NOR.EVENT_START_TIME=2016-05-01 14:06:31 +01:00, , NW_NOR.EVENT_END_TIME=2016-05-01 14:06:31 +01:00, NW_NOR.DURATION=0, NW_NOR.UPLINK_VOL=0, NW_NOR.DOWNLINK_VOL=0, NW_NOR.TOTAL_VOL=0, NW_NOR.RAT_TYPE=2, NW_NOR.HPMN=6213, NW_NOR.VPMN=62130, NW_NOR.ROAM_TYPE=,NW_NOR.GATEWAY_IP_ADDRESS=41.220.67.18, NW_NOR.SERVING_IP_ADDRESS=41.206.6.147$, NW_NOR.APN=web.gprs.mtnnigeria.net, NW_NOR.APN_TYPE=, NW_NOR.CHARGING_CHARACTERISTICS=400, NW_NOR.PAY_TYPE=, NW_NOR.RATING_GROUP=, NW_NOR.APN_RA_FLAG=, NW_NOR.ORIGINAL_FILE_NAME=ABMPG01_20160501140632_49495),None)
c isMap(KEY_JOINS.SUBSCRIBER_ID=621300245125288, KEY_JOIN.CHARGING_ID=2635156471 -> Set((None,Some(NW_NOR.SUBSCRIBER_ID=621300245125288, NW_NOR.CHARGING_ID=2635156471, NW_NOR.Node_ID=, NW_NOR.Start_Time=2016-05-01 14:06:31 +01:00 ,NW_NOR.CDR_SOURCE=, NW_NOR.FILE_POPULATION_TIME=, NW_NOR.CDR_REASON=recordClosure, NW_NOR.PARTIAL_SEQ_NUM=, NW_NOR.PARTIAL_IND=, NW_NOR.TERMINATION_CAUSE=CauseForRecClosing_sGSNChange, NW_NOR.SOURCE_SEQ_NUM=1, NW_NOR.IMSI=621300245125288, NW_NOR.MSISDN=2348133430001, NW_NOR.IMEI=8604700004664707, NW_NOR.UE_IP_ADDRESS=10.145.221.89, NW_NOR.EVENT_START_TIME=2016-05-01 14:06:31 +01:00, , NW_NOR.EVENT_END_TIME=2016-05-01 14:06:31 +01:00, NW_NOR.DURATION=0, NW_NOR.UPLINK_VOL=0, NW_NOR.DOWNLINK_VOL=0, NW_NOR.TOTAL_VOL=0, NW_NOR.RAT_TYPE=2, NW_NOR.HPMN=6213, NW_NOR.VPMN=62130, NW_NOR.ROAM_TYPE=,NW_NOR.GATEWAY_IP_ADDRESS=41.220.67.18, NW_NOR.SERVING_IP_ADDRESS=41.206.6.147$, NW_NOR.APN=web.gprs.mtnnigeria.net, NW_NOR.APN_TYPE=, NW_NOR.CHARGING_CHARACTERISTICS=0400, NW_NOR.PAY_TYPE=, NW_NOR.RATING_GROUP=, NW_NOR.APN_RA_FLAG=, NW_NOR.ORIGINAL_FILE_NAME=ABMPG01_20160501140632_49495),None), (None,Some(NW_NOR.SUBSCRIBER_ID=621300245125288, NW_NOR.CHARGING_ID=2635156471, NW_NOR.Node_ID=, NW_NOR.Start_Time=2016-05-01 14:06:31 +01:00 ,NW_NOR.CDR_SOURCE=, NW_NOR.FILE_POPULATION_TIME=, NW_NOR.CDR_REASON=recordClosure, NW_NOR.PARTIAL_SEQ_NUM=, NW_NOR.PARTIAL_IND=, NW_NOR.TERMINATION_CAUSE=normalRelease, NW_NOR.SOURCE_SEQ_NUM=2, NW_NOR.IMSI=621300245125288, NW_NOR.MSISDN=2348133430001, NW_NOR.IMEI=8604700004664707, NW_NOR.UE_IP_ADDRESS=10.145.221.89, NW_NOR.EVENT_START_TIME=2016-05-01 14:06:31 +01:00, , NW_NOR.EVENT_END_TIME=2016-05-01 14:07:43 +01:00, NW_NOR.DURATION=72, NW_NOR.UPLINK_VOL=288, NW_NOR.DOWNLINK_VOL=224, NW_NOR.TOTAL_VOL=512, NW_NOR.RAT_TYPE=2, NW_NOR.HPMN=6213, NW_NOR.VPMN=62130, NW_NOR.ROAM_TYPE=,NW_NOR.GATEWAY_IP_ADDRESS=41.220.67.18, NW_NOR.SERVING_IP_ADDRESS=41.206.6.147$, NW_NOR.APN=web.gprs.mtnnigeria.net, NW_NOR.APN_TYPE=, NW_NOR.CHARGING_CHARACTERISTICS=0400, NW_NOR.PAY_TYPE=, NW_NOR.RATING_GROUP=, NW_NOR.APN_RA_FLAG=, NW_NOR.ORIGINAL_FILE_NAME=ABMPG01_20160501140747_49534),None)))
2016-09-01 10:01:50,373 [Executor task launch worker-3] ERROR org.apache.spark.executor.Executor - Exception in task 0.0 in stage 994.0 (TID 482)
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.collection.mutable.HashMap cannot be cast to scala.collection.mutable.MultiMap
    at StreamingEngineSt$.trackStateFunc(StreamEngineSt.scala:395)
```

I pasted the exact values of C and value while getting this exception...I get the exception at

```
 if(!c.entryExists(key, _==value.get))
```

but both c and values have correct types

Comment: I am not sure what the exact problem is here, but as an aside I would advise against using MultiMap.  It is all too easy to lose the Multi-ness of it by, for example, using a method that creates a new collection (e.g. filter).  I greatly prefer `Map[Key, List[X]]` or somesuch; even though you need more complex code to add elements, the overall robustness more than makes up for it in my experience.

Answer (score 0):

It was  somehow strange for me, but I had to change the type of 'Set' to an 'ArrayBuffer' so not getting any similar casting exception..perhaps, this is a bug in Spark (1.6)